# Why my spf13 based vim looks terrible

Tags: vim, macvim

I am pretty much new to vim. After using it for some days I decided to install spf13. Unfortunately after installing vim looks much bad than without it. Am I doing something wrong or does it really looks like the way it is looking in the image. Attached both terminal and macvim image.

[image: vim terminal]

[image]

Comment: What don't you like about the appearance?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your terminal supports more than 16 colors, so that's probably not the issue. Rather, *spf-13*'s author has his own prefered *colorscheme* and wants you to use it, too. You can quickly change that with `:colorscheme ...` (e.g. `default`), but to make that persistent you need to find out how to override the *spf-13* setting.

Vim "distributions" like *spf-13* and *Janus* lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense.